# How to replace environment.ts with environment.prod.ts in Angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-workspace-configuration

My goal is to compile Angular application as a library.

The problem is `app1-lib` do not have `fileReplacements`, so when `app1-lib` is compiled. It always use `environment.ts` instead of `environment.prod.ts`.

Is there a way to replace file in angular library?

angular.json

```
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/app1",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1",
            "index": "projects/app1/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app1/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app1/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/app1/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/app1/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "app1:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/app1/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/app1/karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/app1/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app1-lib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/app1",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/app1/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/app1/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/app1/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to have that for a library.

You should likely go with a configuration via providers. You could define a function `provideMyLib()` (like there is `provideHttpclient()` or `provideRouter()`) which would setup the providers for your lib. It's great for DX as autocomplete would suggest all the posible options.

Answer (score 0):

The Approach you may want to follow is to use the environment from your app and use the library functions without any state through an environment.
This is done via [`forRoot` methods](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern). The state is provided into a module and can be accessed as easy as if it was part of the environment of the library.

Comment: there is no `fileReplacements` for angular library.

Comment: I tried `forRoot` and it will not lazy load. It will download `/app1/one` and `/app1/two` when I visit `/app/one`. https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-workspace-example/blob/main/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: It should be called on the lazy-loaded component/module not on the root then. $